# How to add a tag to all Hapi logs in server.ext('onRequest', ...)

Tags: hapi.js

There's obviously an assumption built into this question that this must happen in `server.ext('onRequest', ...)` - this is not the case so could happen somewhere else.

My specific use case is that my service is being called by a Load Tester. That Load Tester provides a specific HTTP header that allows me to identify it. I want to add a specific tag to all of the logs when this header is present.

I would have though that there would be something in the request object or the log property in the request object that I would be able to append a tag to that would be applied to all logs on that request. Can't find anything.

Hapi Version: @hapi/hapi 18.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to put what i put into hapihour here:

You could overwrite the hapi internal log function in a server extension on request to force it to add your custom tag using the following code:

```
    server.ext({
        type: 'onRequest',
        method: function (request, h) {

            const oldLogFxn = request._log;
            const newLogFxn = (tags, data, channel) => oldLogFxn(['CUSTOM_TAG', ...tags], data, channel);
            request._log = newLogFxn.bind(request);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why request._log in this scenario and not request.log?